# map/set iterators incompatible - checking to see if object is in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, find

I'm trying to search my Map to see if the object (message) being taken in by the Person is already contained in their map.

Here's the map container:

```
std::map<MessageContent, unsigned int>  messageList;
```

And here's my call to the find() function:

```
if(listOfPersons.at(y).getMessageList().find(*tempMessage.getMessageContent()) 
                                    != listOfPersons.at(y).getMessageList().end())
```

Here's the getMessageContent():

```
MessageContent* Message::getMessageContent() const
{
    return mc;
}
```

And finally here's the getMessageList() function

```
std::map<MessageContent, unsigned int> Persons::getMessageList() const
{
    return messageList;
}
```

Also related to the topic at hand, I think I'm using `return messageList;` incorrectly, as I think this type of return returns an actual Copy of the messageList, so it's better to use a reference type.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed doing something wrong when you `return messageList`: you're making a copy as you say, and this is not only a problem for performance (potentially), but in your case it's a critical bug, as you call getMessageList() twice and do find() on one of them and end() on the other.  This invokes undefined behavior, as you are then comparing two iterators that came from two different containers.  Make the function return a reference as you suggested, and that problem will be resolved.

Comment: so in that case, do I change the full function definition to 

`std::map<MessageContent, unsigned int>& Persons::getMessageList() const
{
    return messageList;
}`

Comment: I only launched the code with return messageList cause I get funky intelliSense errors regarding the returning messageList as a reference. From what I understand, I declare the return of the `std::map<>&` <-- with the & sign correct? or am i missing more

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  To make it easier to type, write a typedef somewhere for the map type, and use it in all the places.

Comment: After I have changed the declaration to read `std::map<MessageContent, unsigned int>& Persons::getMessageList() const` 
I get errors when just returning `return messageList`. Specifically: `error: qualifiers dropped when binding in reference of type std::map`

Comment: Or is this because I'm using `const` on the end.....because the program compiles after I removed const.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that before--the method cannot be const because it returns a non-const reference.  You're probably better off leaving the method as const, and making the returned reference const as well.

Comment: I'm still stuck on the fact that this `find()` function just won't work. `if(listOfPersons.at(y).getMessageList().find(*tempMessage.getMessageContent()) 
                                    != listOfPersons.at(y).getMessageList().end())` It's my last step in my project and i can't get it to work

Comment: What do you mean "won't work?"  Won't compile?  Crashes?  Calls your mom on the phone and insults her?

Comment: Haha fair enough....poor description. It just will never reach the condition below it. I'm currently trying new code to go around the find and just directly use the `[]` operator to see if the `MessageContent` exists in the map.